# Howto register a webhook with AuthType=HttpHeader using "Dynamics 365 Web API"

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-dynamics

To register a webhook on Dynamics 365 there is a tool called Plug-in Registration (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/register-web-hook).

However, I would like to automate the webhook registration process and thus would like to use the Web API endpoint for webhook registration:

```
/api/data/v9.2/serviceendpoints
```

The problem I have is the setting of the value for the parameter `authvalue` in the JSON request body, because I want to use Http Header `authtype`:

```
{
    "name": "Test Webhook",
    "url": "https://myendpoint",
    "contract": 8,
    "authtype": 5,
    "authvalue": "<========= ??? what comes here ???"
}
```

Assuming I want to have this header be sent to my webhook endpoint:

```
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

What would be the value of `authvalue` in the JSON above ?
The value should be a string according to the data type of authvalue, but how that should be formatted?

If I use the value `Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=` as is for authvalue,
when the webhook is fired, I got the following error in System Job:

> Plugin Trace:
>
> [Microsoft.Crm.ServiceBus: Microsoft.Crm.ServiceBus.WebhookPlugin]
> [ad9a4124-ab57-ec11-8f8f-6045bd8aed3b: Test for Step Creation]
>
> Error Message:
>
> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]:
> The webhook call failed because of invalid http headers in authValue.
> Check if the authValue format, header names and values are valid for
> your Service Endpoint entity. (Fault Detail is equal to Exception
> details:  ErrorCode: 0x80050203 Message: The webhook call failed
> because of invalid http headers in authValue. Check if the authValue
> format, header names and values are valid for your Service Endpoint
> entity. TimeStamp: 2021-12-08T10:15:26.8637496Z
> -- Exception details:  ErrorCode: 0x80040216 Message: Received exception when adding custom http headers: for
> OrgId:xxxxxx-925f-4958-9aee-xxxxxxxxxxxx, serviceEndpointId:
> c099d16c-a057-ec11-8f8f-6045bd8aed3b, name: Test Webhook,
> exception:System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid.
> Line 1, position 1.    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception
> e)    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()    at
> System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()    at
> System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
> preserveWhitespace)    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader
> reader)    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)    at
> Microsoft.Crm.ServiceBus.WebhookClient.ExtractKe...).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For HtppHeader authentication type the key value pair for AuthValue must be set in the following xml format:

```
<settings><setting name="Authorization" value="Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=" /></settings>
```

Comment: Many thanks Felix for the answer. Much appreciated. It works.